# Using the mouse wheel with JSpinner in Java

Tags: java, user-interface

I would like to use my mouse wheel to increment and decrement a JSpinner.  Is this possible?

Comment: I found a hack for this (see my answer and org.life.java's answer below).  But is there a simple switch, setting, or property somewhere that will give the spinner this behavior without writing all that code?

Comment: Do you have tried **something** before asking?

Answer (score 4):

```
import javax.swing.*;
import java.awt.event.*;
public class TestSpinner extends JFrame implements MouseWheelListener
{
  public TestSpinner()
  {
    setSize( 100, 50 );
    spinner = new JSpinner();
    spinner.addMouseWheelListener( this );
    getContentPane().add( spinner, "Center" );
  }
  public void mouseWheelMoved( MouseWheelEvent e )
  {
    spinner.setValue(
        new Integer( ((Integer)spinner.getValue()).intValue() - e.getWheelRotation() ) );
  }
  public static void main( String [] args )
  {
    TestSpinner t = new TestSpinner();
    t.setVisible( true );
  }
  private JSpinner spinner;
}
```

Source: https://www.devx.com/tip-bank/14880/

Comment: This is the solution I ended up using.  But I give a cleaner answer in my own answer.

Answer (score 0):

```
spinner.addMouseWheelListener(new MouseWheelListener() {
    public void mouseWheelMoved(MouseWheelEvent mwe) {
        if (mwe.getScrollType() != MouseWheelEvent.WHEEL_UNIT_SCROLL) {
            return;
        }
        double value = (Double)spinner.getValue();
        value -= mwe.getUnitsToScroll();
        spinner.setValue(value);
    }
});
```

This hack worked for me.

Comment: Note this won't respect minimum and maximum allowable values even if your model (e.g., SpinnerNumberModel) supports that. I manually added checks before calling setValue.